# Network query returns local datastore pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have recently managed to switch to Local Datastore, moving all the needed parts of the database to the client. Furthermore I send a push notification whenever data changes so that the client data stays up to date.

Now my problem is that one of the pointers in my data keeps returning the old pointer after updating.

Here is the code that I use:

```
public ParseQuery<CircuitUnit> circuitUnits() {
    ParseQuery<CircuitUnit> query = CircuitUnit.getQuery();
    query.include(CircuitUnit.circuits);
    query.include(CircuitUnit.guard);
    query.setLimit(1000);
    return query;
}

circuitUnits().findInBackground(
             new FindCallback<CircuitUnit>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<CircuitUnit> objects, ParseException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pinning circuitUnits " + objects.size());

        // debugging loop of results
        for (CircuitUnit circuitUnit : objects) {
            if (circuitUnit.getObjectId().equals("TXEZDch6wK")) {

                Guard guard = circuitUnit.getGuard();
                Log.d(TAG, "Guard: " + guard.getObjectId());

            }
        }

        // This function updates the Local datastore with the newly fetched objects
        // updateServerDataPin(objects, PinsGlobal.CIRCUIT_UNITS,
                            e, callback);
    }
});
```

The Logged output is: "Guard: L440gHXKTY"  where it should be SDDg23rR4h

I have added a screenshot of the CircuitUnit table showing that SDDg23rR4h is indeed the expected objectId of the pointer.

[image: CircuitUnits table shown in Data Browser]

I tried to create a sample project showing the issue as part of the bug report for parse.com, but that returned the correct pointer.

My theory is then that this problem lies in having data in the Local Datastore which somehow interferes with the result. Not that I understand why, cause I am clearly querying the network and not locally.

It seems as if the include statements are ignored and simply filled with the known data from the Local Datastore.

Has anyone experienced something similar or have a possible explanation to this behaviour?

Comment: Same for me, have you an answer for that ?

Comment: Cannot recall having found a solid solution/explanation. I believe I ended up using simple values instead of pointers, that is moving from updating a pointer to updating integer and string values.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I've posted a question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729455/wrong-remote-data-when-enablelocaldatastore-with-parse . Wait and see...