# Wrong remote data when enableLocalDatastore with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have enable Parse local-datastore on my swift application. I want to sync remote data with local but I am facing issues with Pointer Array.

I have a PFSubclass like this :

```
class ShotModel : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
  @NSManaged var status: String?
  @NSManaged var pics: [PicModel]?
}
```

And when I update `status` on Parse server, the data is sync with my local datastore but when update the `pics` Pointer Array, the local data are not changed.

For example:

1. I fetch shots list (Array of Shot) which contain only one shot and its 3 pics.
2. I get the good response from the server (an Array with one shot and its 3 pics)
3. I update this shot on Parse server with 4 pics
4. I re-fetch shots list which is supposed to contain one shot and its 4 pics.
5. The response is now wrong: the shot has only 3 pics

The result of query is :

```
[<Shot: 0x170382d80, objectId: VwA1Qc9NBN, localId: (null)> {
  pics =     (
      "<Pic: 0x14ee64460, objectId: h5TGCb8BAx, localId: (null)> {\n  \n}",
      "<Pic: 0x14ee645d0, objectId: fZ61mvMUAM, localId: (null)> {\n  \n}",
      "<Pic: 0x14ee634f0, objectId: g8Wbxyk8E3, localId: (null)> {\n  \n}"
  );
  status = Done;
}]
```

I get the same result wether I delete one, two or all pics.

When i make a remote fetch, the response query always return old Pointer Array list, I don't know why.

Do you know why parse behaves like that, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: check my answer, seems you had same issue as me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465802/parse-unpin-does-not-remove-object-from-local-datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V1.7.5 — JUNE 24, 2015 fixes this bug 
https://parse.com/docs/downloads